# Donald Sarason's problem X.20.3

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I am thinking maybe I can start with a normal family, but no idea how to go further. Any ideas?

Comment: Here's a starting point. It suffices to find a holomorphic $f$ with the property that every subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ has a further subsequence converging to $f$ and then check that it coincides with Riemann mapping function. Fix a subsequence. Then by the [Fundamental Normality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_normality_test), we can assume that a further subsequence converges to some $f$ (_a priori_ this could converge to $\infty$ but our conditions rule that out.) Now just show that this $f$ is the Riemann mapping function. (e.g. Hurwitz's theorem gives us injectivity.)

Comment: @Blake I think it should be related to the property. And I think in order to find a normal family property, I think we need to show it's locally uniformly bounded, which I haven't figured out a proof.

Comment: If you want to avoid the heavy machinery of the fundamental normality test, then you can use Montel's theorem as follows. $G$ is simply connected, so we can map it conformally onto a bounded domain (e.g. $D$ via the Riemann mapping theorem) through some $\phi :G\to D$. If $\{f_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is the subsequence mentioned previously, then Montel's theorem can be applied to $\{\phi\circ f_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ to yield a limiting function $\tilde{f}$. Unless I'm mistaken, it shouldn't be too hard to show that $f:=\phi^{-1}\circ\tilde{f}$ is what you want.